# How can I construct the main() to output YES if two input streams are equal?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I wish to be advised on how to go about the main() function in order to output this example (below) using the function I created. I need help with creating the main() function to output as the example shows below. Thank you so much.

```
//Question: Given two input stream inputA and inputB, which should have 
//backspace. If the final result of the two input streams is equal, output YES, 
//otherwise output NO.
//Example:
￼//• inputA = "abcde<<", inputB = "abcd<e<", return
//• Explanation: The final result of inputA and inputB is ￼ so return "YES"
//• inputA = "a<<bc", inputB = "abc<", return
//• Explanation: The final result of inputA is and the final result of inputB is 
// "ab", so return "NO"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

bool input_stream(string inputA, string inputB);

int main()
{

}

bool input_stream(string inputA, string inputB)
{
   stack<char> stack1, stack2;
   string::iterator iter1, iter2;
   for (iter1 = inputA.begin(); iter1 < inputA.end(); ++iter1)
   {
      if(*iter1 == ‘<‘)
        if(!stack1.empty())
          stack1.pop();
      else
        stack1.push(*iter1);
   }
   for (iter2 = inputB.begin(); iter2 < inputB.end(); ++iter2)
   {
      if(*iter2 == ‘<‘)
        if (!stack2.empty())
          stack2.pop();
      else
        stack2.push(*iter2);
   }
   if (stack1 == stack2)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Asking for "Any advice, suggestion, or explanation" may be considered too broad by some and therefore get your question closed. Be specific.

Comment: Stack is not needed there

Comment: @NickyC thank you, I have now edited the question.

Comment: @S.M. I have to use stack for this specific problem

Comment: `if` ... `if` ... `else` is inconsistent with the code alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your `input_stream()` function working correctly, writing the `main()` function is the easy part.

Your function accepts 2 strings - so pass 2 strings to your function and check the value that your function returns with an `if` statement. Then write the appropriate results to the screen using `cout`.

You can either store the result in an additional variable and check *that* in the `if` statement's condition, or just use the function call itself as the condition since it returns `bool` already.